# Using Roxygen2 for my utility functions

Tags: r, documentation, roxygen2

In my analysis projects (not a package), I usually have utility functions that I `source()` in different analysis scripts.

I've been using the Roxygen2 documentation convention (e.g. starting the documentation with `#'`, which is well supported in RStudio.

Can I make these documentation available via `help(my_utility_function)`? Everything I read so far uses `Roxygen2` and `devtools::document()` in the context of a package. Indeed, when I tried to use `devtools::document()`, it complains about not being able to find the package root.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to make it into a package.

Comment: Do you have any solution for documenting utility functions? Should I just "go to source" when I want to understand its argument?

Comment: @Heisenberg my recommendation would be to... make a package. :) It's also a neat way to distribute your work.